# hosting a GWT application on private machine

Tags: gwt, web-hosting

I have a GWT application for some highcharts visualizations, that accesses Cassandra database in the back end. Obviously, because of privacy of data in the database I can not host the application on Google App Engine.

This application being a private one which is used by very few people, I dont expect lot of traffic.So, I was thinking of hosting the application on my own machine.

Please some one tell me is it good idea?, and how to go about implementing that.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem at all, just set up some application server, like Tomcat, compile your gwt project, and export the war folder to the Tomcats webapps folder. Your war contents should have following structure (or similar):

```
project_name.war
   - css
   - images
   - WEB-INF
   - gwt compiled_javascript folder
   - index.html
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. However, my confusion here is about configuring my own machine to be a server. Like registering for a DNS name etc.. How can that be done without any cost/less cost?..

Comment: Well to register a domain need you will need to spend some money. Also, hosting will require more finances, depending on hosting. If you are not on the same network, you might want to consider making you localhost available to an outer world, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579939/how-to-make-my-localhost-available-over-internet for reference

Comment: Sure.. I want to skip DNS step. just want my application to be accessed from outside world like xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/application ? Is it possible?..   I appreciate your help.. Thanks..